# Mysterious Divi child theme css being ignored

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

this is driving me insane.

child theme .css is loaded, after the parent style, but the CSS is just not applied / doesn't override, I've searched around and I see several other people complaining about this.

Enqueing the style or even adding priority to it does not solve it.

Adding the same CSS via the theme customizer, the CSS is actually applied, so the CSS itself is not the problem here.

What can I do more?!

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the parent css in question (or some of it), the child css (or some of it), if you're using chrome could you do a screenshot of the inspect console to see the strike through (usually indicates it has been overridden by another script)? Then hopefully some members with experience in this may be able to provide more suggestions.

Comment: I did use the inspect and it just was not overriding, change some setting in the enque function finally made it work (after trying several different enque settings)

Comment: @Aliqua, I’ve seen a few answers from you now and you see to ask everyone to accept your answer - it’s frowned upon to be so demanding. It is up to the person who’s answer they accept (or if they accept any, even though it is the preferred practice on Stack Overflow). They also need time to get and try other answers before deciding.

Comment: You haven’t provided us with your code, which is one of the fundamental requirements for questions on Stack Overflow, along with details of what you tried yourself (so we don’t suggest them again). For future reference, I suggest reviewing [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and see how to add your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have all information we need next time and can offer more specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included a dependency in the `wp_enqueue_script()`?

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
    Example...
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'stylesheet-name', // it will append '-css' in your source
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/stylesheet-name.css',
        array('parent-style'), // dependants (reliable on other stylesheet)
        'null',  // version, null or version number (1.0.1 etc)
        'all' // media
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Note: if you have a version number in your enqueue then the cache could stop it from loading. Some people use `date()` to change the value each time it refreshes...

Comment: I tried the date method but it was not a chaching issue, just wasnt overriding, later I finally found an enque setting that worked, I anwsered bellow.

Comment: I actually ran into this problem again, edited my awnser to include the style registration before enqueing, that solved that one problem also.

Comment: Good work! Glad you worked it out. Goodluck with your project!

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted your awnser as the correct one (don't understand why I get a downvote as this is very specific to Divi...), but thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an enque setting that solves it,

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { 

wp_register_style( 
    'child-style', 
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
    array(), 
    filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ) 
  );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-style') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

apparently what made a difference for me is the "array('parent-style')" value in the function atributes, must investigate it further but this was the only thing that solved it.

Comment: You add the child style *before* the parent style in your code so that means it was being loaded first, and *then* the parent which would override the child styles. Adding the parent-style dependency means that the ‘parent-style` css must be loaded first before your `child-style`. Also, I don't see a real difference in the concept behind this and Aliqua’s answer except you include more of your own code (and you don’t seem to understand it :) ). This is what @Aliqua ‘s answer said to do based on having no code to work with! You should consider accepting that answer as it is the basis for yours.

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept Fluffy awnser no problem, but very specifically "my" code is what actually works, also the parent-style was always enqued firs before the child, but only the array('parent-style') loads it correctly and allows override. Divi theme behaves differently then other themes, this is the only thing that seemed to work so I pasted the code here to help because the other awnsers on other threads here don't seem to be working anymore or at least didn't work for me.

Comment: It’s not my answer :) but your answer is an implementation of the other answer specific to your code (when you didn’t include the code in your question, that was as good a solution as you could get). As I said, the dependency works because it tells WP that the `parent-style` must be loaded first before `child-style` no matter where they are enqueued or in what order. It’s relatively common to specify css and js dependencies in child theme development as it takes the uncertainty out of the enqueuing order, so it’s a good practice to get into using in any other themes to might work on too.